# Why does key takes too long for this algorithm in java mean : Session.connect: java.security.InvalidKeyException

Tags: java, unix

I have seen many people have asked this question and answered it too. Sorry, but I am very new to java and I don't really understand the concept and the way to solve this error. Please provide to me a way to solve this problem.

I use

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

javac 1.8.0_77
```

I checked the JCE strength using the code below :

```
package automation;    
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Mainjava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
                String cryptoAlg = "AES";
                try{
                    SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[32], cryptoAlg);
                    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(cryptoAlg + "/CBC/NoPadding");
                    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
                    System.out.println("Success");
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.err.println("************ The Java Virtual Machine can't handle strong cryptography.\n************ This will lead to problems with some services and subsystems!");
                }
            }   }
```

And in the above code, i didn't get an error message.

Can you tell me where my mistake is? Here is my code where I am trying to connect with the unix server.

```
    package automation;
import java.io.*;                             
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;     

public class unixConnect {                    
            public static void main(String[] args) {  
                  try{                                                             
                          System.out.println("Inside ConnectEC2");                       
                           JSch jsch=new JSch();                                         
                           System.out.println("setting pem file");                       
                           System.out.println("added key");                              
                           JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");                

                           String password = "Star3009";
                           System.out.println("giving userid");            
                           Session session=jsch.getSession("mon387", "jackets", 22 );
                           session.setPassword(password);
                           System.out.println("trying to connect");               
                           int port1 = session.getPort();                         
                           System.out.println("port1:"+ port1);                   
                           session.connect(3000);                                 
                           System.out.println("connected");                       
                           String command = "cat Mon_Non_Mon_No_Diff.dat;";                                
                           Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");         
                           channel.setInputStream(null);                          
                           channel.setOutputStream(System.out);                   

                           ( (ChannelExec) channel ).setCommand( command );       
                           channel.connect();                                     

                           InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();          
                           byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];                           

                           while (true) {                                         
                              while (input.available() > 0) {                            
                                  int i = input.read(tmp, 0, 1024);                      
                                  if (i < 0) break;                                      
                                  System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));               
                              }                                                          
                              if (channel.isClosed()){                                   
                                  System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());

                                  break;                                                 
                              }                                                          
                          }                                                              
                          Thread.sleep(1000);                                            
                          channel.disconnect();                                          
                          session.disconnect();                                          
                     }                                                                   
                     catch(Exception e){                                                 
                       System.out.println(e);                                            
                     }                                                                   
                  }                                                                      
}
```

Update :
 Output of the above code :

```
 Inside ConnectEC2
setting pem file
added key
giving userid
trying to connect
port1:22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for this algorithm
```

Comment: What error does it give you? provide more information on the error/line etc.

Comment: The below is the output of the code :                                                   Inside ConnectEC2
setting pem file
added key
giving userid
trying to connect
port1:22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for this algorithm

Comment: please, add it in post as an UPDATE in the end of it, it is not readable this way, tnx :)

Comment: updated the output...Please help me in solving the error....I tried as much as I can

Comment: if you would check here---> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/InvalidKeyException.html
  you could see that the exception it is throwing to you is because the key you are trying to send has either invalid encoding, wrong length, uninitialized, etc. So the problem is the key you are trying to authenticate with. As it says the key is too long for this algorithm, so i can suppose that you are providing the wrong key.... If you can define it, make it smaller. and give me feedback of the results.

Comment: can I display the current key value that is using, if so how can I display it ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111402/discussion-between-svati-and-hedgehog).

Answer (score 0):

From what i researched now, i can see that many other had the same problem as you, problem is not on your code, it was a bug of JDK which was filled and fixed as they said so updating to Java SE 8u45 (or higher) should solve the issue. Also update the jsch to 0.1.50  version.

Although, you have a second exception.. the JSchException, seems like you are not using the correct port to connect with the server. The issue is, it is waiting indefinitely for the negotiation to complete. It is a Mexican stand-off with neither side giving up. Call session.setTimeout() before session.connect(), or call session.connect(timeout), with some suitable value (3-5 seconds). I believe the timeout is in milliseconds. Also update the jsch to 0.1.50 +version.

Also, if you are using public-key authentication, JSch is expecting the public-key file in the same directory (and same name with an added .pub).

The reason is that in the SSH public key authentication protocol, the client first sends a list of the available public keys to the server, and the server from these selects a fitting one - only then the private key is needed (and will be decrypted, if necessary). While it (depending of the algorithm and key representation) might be possible to calculate the public key from the private one, JSch doesn't do this itself, so you'll have to provide both keys.